Driver compatibility issue with linux dual boot, keyboard not working after grub
My keyboard works in GRUB but after that everything stops working
I've been trying to run GParted to resize some partitions however I encountered a problem where my keyboard would work for the first section. And then the next stage where it'd ask me about keymaps, it'd just stop working. At first I thought this was a GParted problem and installed an older version tried GPT instead of MBR, double checked UEFI settings and it still didn't work.
I've tried GPT and MBR as well as DD and ISO.
I then tried Kali Linux to see if it'd work and the exact same thing happened it'd work for the first screen and then stop working.
My keyboard works perfectly in Windows, but as soon as I dual boot it stops working.
I tried installing my drivers for my Surface (Surface Pro 10 for Business)
However it didn't work.
Kali Linux and GParted previously worked on my Surface Pro (5th Gen) 256 GB, i7, 8GB RAM, with no need to install any drivers or anything so it  makes me think it's a Linux drivers issue.
This is what the Microsoft worker told me here https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/surface/forum/surfaceaccesso-surfver_accesso-surftop_keyboard/surface-keyboard-not-working-in-dual-boot/85761d2c-dba9-4a87-a568-df37632e6058
I don't know what I should do now.
I've tried different versions of GParted and Rufus already.
I'm using the NetInstaller in the Installer images tab. I'm waiting for my 16GB USB to arrive so I can try the Live Boot and the regular Installer image.
I know this could be avoided with a USB Keyboard and mouse but I don't want to have to resort to buying this.
I've updated all things when it comes to windows (the PC and keyboard etc...)
I've tried different keyboards (the same model) and have seen no results.
I've looked at my UEFI settings and there's nothing more I can change.

I've disabled secure boot, secured core and made sure all things listed under the devices tab are enabled.
Surface Pro Model: Surface Pro 10 for business
Keyboard model: Surface Pro Keyboard
